# Exibir um valor com os centavos não zerados e utilizando Float?

Tags: java

Tem alguma forma de fazer com que os centavos não sejam cortados com tipo Float?

Estou convertento um valor para ser formatado com DecimalFormat para que parece os centavos dessa forma:

```
    Float numero = 2564786549.87543771885808f;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");  
    System.out.println(df.format(numero));
```

Eu preciso que seja exibido isso:

2564786432,54

Só que desse jeito está zerando os centavos, teria como manter nçao zerar os centavos?

Ps.: Não posso usar double.

Comment: Pra moedas, o recomendado é utilizar [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), ou você terá prejuizos(ou seu cliente rs) pois float e double são péssimos em se tratando de precisão decimal.

Comment: Aproveitando o comentário anterior, verifique com base no BigDecimal a formatação que você deseja. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195837/format-float-to-n-decimal-places

Comment: Vou trocar para esse, espera.

Comment: Não pode usar nem `double`, nem `float`. Isso é um erro que não tem como arrumar sem usar o tipo certo, mesmo que pareça que arrumou e isso é um perigo porque é fácil fazer parecer que arrumou.

Comment: Okay, entendido...Nunca tinha utilizado o BigDecimal

Answer (score 1):

Olá, recomendo a leitura [Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) sera útil!

Trecho tirado da fonte: These methods, ***format*** and ***printf***, are ***equivalent*** to one another!

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TestFormat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      long n = 461012;
      System.out.format("%d%n", n);      //  -->  "461012"
      System.out.format("%08d%n", n);    //  -->  "00461012"
      System.out.format("%+8d%n", n);    //  -->  " +461012"
      System.out.format("%,8d%n", n);    // -->  " 461,012"
      System.out.format("%+,8d%n%n", n); //  -->  "+461,012"

      double pi = Math.PI;

      System.out.format("%f%n", pi);       // -->  "3.141593"
      System.out.format("%.3f%n", pi);     // -->  "3.142"
      System.out.format("%10.3f%n", pi);   // -->  "     3.142"
      System.out.format("%-10.3f%n", pi);  // -->  "3.142"
      System.out.format(Locale.FRANCE,
                        "%-10.4f%n%n", pi); // -->  "3,1416"

      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      System.out.format("%tB %te, %tY%n", c, c, c); // -->  "May 29, 2006"

      System.out.format("%tl:%tM %tp%n", c, c, c);  // -->  "2:34 am"

      System.out.format("%tD%n", c);    // -->  "05/29/06"
    }
}
```